# CodeGuard in C++Builder 11 Alexandria

Tags: c++builder-11-alexandria

I can't get C++Builder 11 to link a project with CodeGuard. Not even with a new C++Builder VCL Application project.

I have tried various permutations of `implib` options (`-a -c -f`) on `cg32.dll` to create `cg32.lib`. The linker always comes back with multiple "unresolved external" errors from `PROJECT1.OBJ` / `UNIT1.OBJ`, like so:

```
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_CG_DESC' referenced from C:\PROJECT\TEST\000\WIN32\DEBUG\PROJECT1.OBJ
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_CG_THIS' referenced from C:\PROJECT\TEST\000\WIN32\DEBUG\UNIT1.OBJ
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_CG_DTORTHIS' referenced from C:\PROJECT\TEST\000\WIN32\DEBUG\UNIT1.OBJ
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_CG_DA_EPY' referenced from C:\PROJECT\TEST\000\WIN32\DEBUG\UNIT1.OBJ
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_CG_A_BP' referenced from C:\PROJECT\TEST\000\WIN32\DEBUG\UNIT1.OBJ
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_CG_A_PY' referenced from C:\PROJECT\TEST\000\WIN32\DEBUG\UNIT1.OBJ
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_CG_GDA_EGY' referenced from C:\PROJECT\TEST\000\WIN32\DEBUG\PROJECT1.OBJ
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link
Failed
Elapsed time: 00:00:01.4
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I've *never* had good luck trying to use CodeGuard, so I always just leave it disabled.

Comment: My memory of it is similar, now that I think of it. I was told that the C++Builder 6 code I am porting to Alexandria leaks memory and that users need to restart to get around this - so I thought I would give it a try but as far as I can tell it just doesn't work.